# Nessus Windows Compliance Check Issue

Tags: audit, nessus

My team and I have been trying to troubleshoot an issue we have had with the Windows compliance check not working for a custom audit. We have enabled firewall and printer connections, tried disabling port scanning, and  re-loaded all the plugins. What we are trying to accomplish is a Windows content compliance check to find a specific file that we define in our custom made audit file.

All we get is port scanning results without it looking for the actual file.  Completely lost where to go from here if anyone has some ideas why Nessus is not finding the “ roll loads tool” excel file.

Comment: This is a question for Nessus support.

Comment: I'd say your best bet is to ask on the Tenable Nessus support forums for this, they're usually pretty good at coming up with answers.